# Can Wedderburn's theorem proof be given by integral domain argument directly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Wedderburn's theorem  states as every finite division ring is field
And we know that every Finite integral domain is field. 
So why not we are using that fact to prove that theorem?
As every division ring is integral domain.

I don't know any shortfall in my question but this question came just in my mind And I can not have any argument against it.
That's why I was asking 
Please help me out

Comment: Hi, the part you're missing is that division rings aren't necessarily commutative but integral domains are.

Comment: Thanks  a lot...